# Retrieve and parse XMLresponse from the SOAP api call

Tags: json, node.js, xml, soap

I used this code to get retrieve the JSON response.

```js
var loopback = require('loopback');
var ds = loopback.createDataSource('soap', {
  connector: require('loopback-connector-soap'),
  wsdl: 'http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL', // The url to WSDL
  url: 'http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx', // The service endpoint

  // Map SOAP service/port/operation to Node.js methods
  operations: {
    // The key is the method name
    stockQuote: {
      service: 'StockQuote', // The WSDL service name
      port: 'StockQuoteSoap', // The WSDL port name
      operation: 'GetQuote' // The WSDL operation name
    },
    // The key is the method name
    stockQuote12: {
      service: 'StockQuote', // The WSDL service name
      port: 'StockQuoteSoap12', // The WSDL port name
      operation: 'GetQuote' // The WSDL operation name
    }
  }

});

//  wait for the methods to be injected
ds.once('connected', function() {
  // Create the model
  var StockQuote = ds.createModel('StockQuote', {});

  StockQuote.stockQuote({
    symbol: 'IBM'
  }, function(err, response) {
    console.log('Response: ', response);
  });

  StockQuote.stockQuote12({
    symbol: 'FB'
  }, function(err, response) {
    console.log('Response: ', response);
  });


});
```

I got the following response.Screenshot shown below.
[image]
Now how do I access each element of the response?
I tried doing in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013909/json-extract-and-use-data-node-js) way,

```
var testout= response["Stock"].Symbol;
console.log(testout);
```

But I just got an error.

How is it possible to access each XML fields of the response?

The got the initial source code from  [here](https://github.com/strongloop-community/loopback-example-connector/blob/soap/stock-ws.js) FYI.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The JSON `GetQuoteResult` field does contain an XML string actually. Jackson is often used to marshal XML and/or JSON payloads to POJOs and vice versa.