# How to extract the message value from JSON in Node.js

Tags: node.js

***My JSON is:***

```
body = 
{  
"session_id":"45470003-6b84-4a2b-bf35-e850d1e2df8b",   
"message":"Thanks for calling service desk, may I know the store number you are calling from?", 
"callstatus":"InProgress", 
"intent":"",  
"responseStatusCode":null,  
"responseStatusMsg":null,  
 "context":"getstorenumber"  
}
```

How to get message value using **Node js**? Please let me know after testing.
i tried **body.message** and **body['message']** and also **body[0]['message']**. I am always getting **"undefined"**

Comment: Check this out -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013909/json-extract-and-use-data-node-js

Comment: If that's really JSON?  If that json was in a javasript variable then either of these will work: body.message and body['message']. Post your actual code.

Comment: Please add code where you are trying to access. this might be due to asynchronous functions.

Comment: @RobertMoskal...   I will get a JSON response like that when i hit my personal service link, where i have to extract the message part alone.   I am sorry i cannot post the full code here.

Comment: @Dinesh sorry i didn't get you. What code should i add?

Comment: just post the code where you are trying to access body

Comment: Use JSON.parse.body and  console.log(body.message)

Comment: Thanks @JomyJoseph it worked really!!!!!!   I was wrong. As per my code the input was a JSON string , then using JSON.parse.body i converted to JSON object. Then i got the message through console.log(body.message)

Comment: @Chris added same in answer section

Answer (score 0):

@Chris comment, since the problem is sorted out, Adding the answer to all members for future ref.
From node.js result, `body` is taken as JSON string, using `JSON.parse.body` converted to json object.

```js
body = 
{  
"session_id":"45470003-6b84-4a2b-bf35-e850d1e2df8b",   
"message":"Thanks for calling service desk, may I know the store number you are calling from?", 
"callstatus":"InProgress", 
"intent":"",  
"responseStatusCode":null,  
"responseStatusMsg":null,  
 "context":"getstorenumber"  
}

JSON.parse.body

console.log(body.message);
```